# Access Pervasive/Btrieve DB (DDF + DAT files) from Java

Tags: java, database, pervasive, btrieve, ddf

I have a folder with *.DDF and *.DAT files that are a pervasive/btrieve database. I am able to open and see the content of the database with DDF Periscope (ddf-periscope.com).

I can export data from each table individually using ddf periscope, and I would like to do the same thing using Java. Access the data in the DB and export them to a CSV file, POJOs or any way I can manipulate the data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either JDBC or the JCL interfaces to access the data.  You do still need the Pervasive engine but you can use Java.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477378/creating-java-connector-for-pervasive) is a simple sample for the JDBC driver.
I don't have a JCL sample but there should be one in the Pervasive / Actian Java Class Library SDK.

Comment: Thank you for you response. Although I still am curious about how does the ddf-periscope retrieve the data without the perasive engine. I would like to write a program that would take in the pervasive database (dat and ddf files), somehow parse them and automatically import the data into a newer sql database, for example postgres. Is that possible?

Comment: DDF-Periscope still uses a Pervasive engine.  In order to access a Pervasive/Btrieve/Actian data file, you must have an engine somewhere.  From the ddf-periscope.com site (http://ddf-periscope.com/features.html): "For operation editor base functions the library of client access to Btrieve server is required. For operation of all editor functions (for example, monitoring) it's necessary install a client part of access to Pervasive. SQL."

Comment: As for your second question about migrating data from Pervasive to Postgres (for example), yes it is possible.  You'll need to cycle through the table in Pervasive, create a new table (or use an existing table in your new database) and insert / update the record.  THere are tools that can do it like the Data Integrator too from Actian.

Comment: So just to be sure - the ddf-periscope accesses the pervasive engine, sets up a connection with it, imports the files into that database and shows that?

Comment: actually nevermind, i connected to the DB, although I had to get the JDBC driver from DbSchema and I can't find the driver v2 anywhere :) but it's something,I'll be looking for the v2, thank you again